# Fast Java JSON Schema Validator for large files

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I need to validate large JSON files (potentially in GB's) against JSON schemas in java.

Any pointers on the library that I could use to do this in the SAX way(as opposed to the DOM way) and ways to keep it generic?

Comment: I've written just such a library. It's currently in beta but within 1 or 2 weeks of a 1.0.0 release. If you have some good test data I'd love to test and tune it with that. https://github.com/worldturner/medeia-validator

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the files as its critical data. I tested it on a 900MB file and it was super-fast. We could validate it in 44 sec. Are you supporting this library? 
 My colleague has raised a github issue there. Is there anyway we could fix that? Thanks!